# Creating a `newtype Maybe a`

Tags: haskell, newtype

I created a `newtype` for `Maybe Int`:

```
Prelude> newtype MaybeTuple = MaybeTuple { getMaybe :: Maybe Int}
Prelude> let m = MaybeTuple (Just 5)
Prelude> getMaybe m
Just 5
```

But how can I create a generic `newtype` of `Maybe a`?

Comment: `MaybeTuple` is a weird name for something wrapping a `Maybe Int`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Add the `a` as a type parameter:

```
newtype MaybeTuple a = MaybeTuple { getMaybe :: Maybe a }
```